# "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I follow steps by step with https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#how-to-obtain-the-credentials-to-communicate-with-google-analytics

but I got { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "errors": [ { "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions" } ] } }

please help me, I've searched and followed all the solutions. but I also got this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64898344/google-analytics-user-does-not-have-sufficient-permissions-for-this-profile suggests that what the tutorial suggested of *Create universal analytics property only* is **wrong** you need to create both google analytics 4 and universal analytics and enable Enhanced measurement. Sidenote: as far as I know GA is discontinuing use of universal analytics in favour of GA 4 which is something to keep in mind if this library does not support it.

Comment: Universal analytics property is still working as Im still using GAnalytics on Laravel 9 projects. I followed the exact step as the OP shared and had no issues.